# How do I associate a reply email to a Lead with an Inbound Email Handler?

Tags: apex, apex-email-service

I am attempting to create an inbound email service that will add attachments to a Lead. The basic flow is:

```
send an email with Apex to the Lead -> Lead replies to the email -> Inbound email service associates the attachments with the correct lead
```

The approaches I have considered:

1. Look up Lead by email address

   This is the approach I see most recommended and in online examples, however the data may contain multiple Lead records with the same email address. This is a data issue that unfortunately is something I have to live with.
2. Use a custom email header

   I thought I could potentially place a custom email header in the outgoing email message for the Lead ID, but it appears custom headers are not possible using `SingleEmailMessage`. Further, it does not appear email clients return the headers in replies.
3. Put the Lead ID in the subject line

   This method works but is prone to error. As it will fail if the subject line is changed. Also, I'm not crazy about the idea of putting record IDs in a subject line.
4. Use the InboundEmail.inReplyTo

   This is my preferred approach. I would like to be able to retrieve the message ID from the `InboudEmail.inReplyTo` field and look up the Lead using that ID. However, I can't find any method of retrieving the original email Message-ID (the value set in the email header) when sending an email with `Messaging.sendEmail(...)`

Is there a way to get the get the Message-ID header value for an email sent from Apex `Messaging.sendEmail`?

Is there a better or alternative solution?